# TableSorter StickyHeaders Widget not working on Multiple Tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6cw0qys4/

I am trying to use multiple tables using jQuery's TableSorter plugin with "StickyHeaders" Widget, its working fine on the first table but not on the next. Only the widget is not working on the 2nd table.

Please advice, thanks!

Here's the JS Code:

```
$(function(){

    /* make second table scroll within its wrapper */
    $(".tablesorter").tablesorter({
        widthFixed : true,
        headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}', // Add icon for various themes

        widgets: [ 'zebra', 'stickyHeaders', 'filter' ],

        widgetOptions: {
            // jQuery selector or object to attach sticky header to
            stickyHeaders_attachTo : '.wrapper' // or $('.wrapper')
        }
    });


});
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div class="narrow-block wrapper">
    <table class="tablesorter">
        <caption class="dark-row">Student Grades</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Account #</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Total</th><th>Discount</th><th>Diff</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>A43</td><td>Peter</td><td>Parker</td><td>28</td><td>9.99</td><td>20.3%</td><td>+3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A255</td><td>John</td><td>Hood</td><td>33</td><td>19.99</td><td>25.1%</td><td>-7</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A33</td><td>Clark</td><td>Kent</td><td>18</td><td>15.49</td><td>44.2%</td><td>-13</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A11</td><td>Bruce</td><td>Almighty</td><td>45</td><td>153.19</td><td>44%</td><td>+19</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A102</td><td>Bruce</td><td>Evans</td><td>56</td><td>153.19</td><td>23%</td><td>+9</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A23</td><td>Mike</td><td>Peters</td><td>22</td><td>5.69</td><td>20.3%</td><td>+2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A55</td><td>Leslie</td><td>Kent</td><td>33</td><td>15.99</td><td>25.1%</td><td>-3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A3</td><td>Frank</td><td>Mint</td><td>44</td><td>12.59</td><td>44.2%</td><td>-12</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A21</td><td>Joe</td><td>Thomas</td><td>45</td><td>15.25</td><td>44%</td><td>+12</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A12</td><td>Tess</td><td>Evans</td><td>66</td><td>13.59</td><td>23%</td><td>+4</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A21</td><td>Peter</td><td>Dunn</td><td>12</td><td>2.99</td><td>21.1%</td><td>+2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A33</td><td>Harry</td><td>Jones</td><td>13</td><td>19.49</td><td>22.2%</td><td>-6</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A13</td><td>John</td><td>James</td><td>16</td><td>13.89</td><td>42.1%</td><td>-13</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A71</td><td>Nick</td><td>Parker</td><td>45</td><td>13.89</td><td>44%</td><td>+29</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A21</td><td>Charles</td><td>Dunn</td><td>19</td><td>15.49</td><td>22%</td><td>+3</td></tr><tr><td>A43</td><td>Peter</td><td>Parker</td><td>28</td><td>9.99</td><td>20.3%</td><td>+3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A255</td><td>John</td><td>Hood</td><td>33</td><td>19.99</td><td>25.1%</td><td>-7</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A33</td><td>Clark</td><td>Kent</td><td>18</td><td>15.49</td><td>44.2%</td><td>-13</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A11</td><td>Bruce</td><td>Almighty</td><td>45</td><td>153.19</td><td>44%</td><td>+19</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A102</td><td>Bruce</td><td>Evans</td><td>56</td><td>153.19</td><td>23%</td><td>+9</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A23</td><td>Mike</td><td>Peters</td><td>22</td><td>5.69</td><td>20.3%</td><td>+2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A55</td><td>Leslie</td><td>Kent</td><td>33</td><td>15.99</td><td>25.1%</td><td>-3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A3</td><td>Frank</td><td>Mint</td><td>44</td><td>12.59</td><td>44.2%</td><td>-12</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A21</td><td>Joe</td><td>Thomas</td><td>45</td><td>15.25</td><td>44%</td><td>+12</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A12</td><td>Tess</td><td>Evans</td><td>66</td><td>13.59</td><td>23%</td><td>+4</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A21</td><td>Peter</td><td>Dunn</td><td>12</td><td>2.99</td><td>21.1%</td><td>+2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A33</td><td>Harry</td><td>Jones</td><td>13</td><td>19.49</td><td>22.2%</td><td>-6</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A13</td><td>John</td><td>James</td><td>16</td><td>13.89</td><td>42.1%</td><td>-13</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A71</td><td>Nick</td><td>Parker</td><td>45</td><td>13.89</td><td>44%</td><td>+29</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A21</td><td>Charles</td><td>Dunn</td><td>19</td><td>15.49</td><td>22%</td><td>+3</td></tr><tr><td>A43</td><td>Peter</td><td>Parker</td><td>28</td><td>9.99</td><td>20.3%</td><td>+3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A255</td><td>John</td><td>Hood</td><td>33</td><td>19.99</td><td>25.1%</td><td>-7</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A33</td><td>Clark</td><td>Kent</td><td>18</td><td>15.49</td><td>44.2%</td><td>-13</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A11</td><td>Bruce</td><td>Almighty</td><td>45</td><td>153.19</td><td>44%</td><td>+19</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A102</td><td>Bruce</td><td>Evans</td><td>56</td><td>153.19</td><td>23%</td><td>+9</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A23</td><td>Mike</td><td>Peters</td><td>22</td><td>5.69</td><td>20.3%</td><td>+2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A55</td><td>Leslie</td><td>Kent</td><td>33</td><td>15.99</td><td>25.1%</td><td>-3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A3</td><td>Frank</td><td>Mint</td><td>44</td><td>12.59</td><td>44.2%</td><td>-12</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A21</td><td>Joe</td><td>Thomas</td><td>45</td><td>15.25</td><td>44%</td><td>+12</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A12</td><td>Tess</td><td>Evans</td><td>66</td><td>13.59</td><td>23%</td><td>+4</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A21</td><td>Peter</td><td>Dunn</td><td>12</td><td>2.99</td><td>21.1%</td><td>+2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A33</td><td>Harry</td><td>Jones</td><td>13</td><td>19.49</td><td>22.2%</td><td>-6</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A13</td><td>John</td><td>James</td><td>16</td><td>13.89</td><td>42.1%</td><td>-13</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A71</td><td>Nick</td><td>Parker</td><td>45</td><td>13.89</td><td>44%</td><td>+29</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A21</td><td>Charles</td><td>Dunn</td><td>19</td><td>15.49</td><td>22%</td><td>+3</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>


<div class="narrow-block wrapper">
    <table class="tablesorter">
        <caption class="dark-row">Student Grades</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Account #</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Total</th><th>Discount</th><th>Diff</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>A43</td><td>Peter</td><td>Parker</td><td>28</td><td>9.99</td><td>20.3%</td><td>+3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A255</td><td>John</td><td>Hood</td><td>33</td><td>19.99</td><td>25.1%</td><td>-7</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A33</td><td>Clark</td><td>Kent</td><td>18</td><td>15.49</td><td>44.2%</td><td>-13</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A11</td><td>Bruce</td><td>Almighty</td><td>45</td><td>153.19</td><td>44%</td><td>+19</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A102</td><td>Bruce</td><td>Evans</td><td>56</td><td>153.19</td><td>23%</td><td>+9</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A23</td><td>Mike</td><td>Peters</td><td>22</td><td>5.69</td><td>20.3%</td><td>+2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A55</td><td>Leslie</td><td>Kent</td><td>33</td><td>15.99</td><td>25.1%</td><td>-3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A3</td><td>Frank</td><td>Mint</td><td>44</td><td>12.59</td><td>44.2%</td><td>-12</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A21</td><td>Joe</td><td>Thomas</td><td>45</td><td>15.25</td><td>44%</td><td>+12</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A12</td><td>Tess</td><td>Evans</td><td>66</td><td>13.59</td><td>23%</td><td>+4</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A21</td><td>Peter</td><td>Dunn</td><td>12</td><td>2.99</td><td>21.1%</td><td>+2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A33</td><td>Harry</td><td>Jones</td><td>13</td><td>19.49</td><td>22.2%</td><td>-6</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A13</td><td>John</td><td>James</td><td>16</td><td>13.89</td><td>42.1%</td><td>-13</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A71</td><td>Nick</td><td>Parker</td><td>45</td><td>13.89</td><td>44%</td><td>+29</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A21</td><td>Charles</td><td>Dunn</td><td>19</td><td>15.49</td><td>22%</td><td>+3</td></tr><tr><td>A43</td><td>Peter</td><td>Parker</td><td>28</td><td>9.99</td><td>20.3%</td><td>+3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A255</td><td>John</td><td>Hood</td><td>33</td><td>19.99</td><td>25.1%</td><td>-7</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A33</td><td>Clark</td><td>Kent</td><td>18</td><td>15.49</td><td>44.2%</td><td>-13</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A11</td><td>Bruce</td><td>Almighty</td><td>45</td><td>153.19</td><td>44%</td><td>+19</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A102</td><td>Bruce</td><td>Evans</td><td>56</td><td>153.19</td><td>23%</td><td>+9</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A23</td><td>Mike</td><td>Peters</td><td>22</td><td>5.69</td><td>20.3%</td><td>+2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A55</td><td>Leslie</td><td>Kent</td><td>33</td><td>15.99</td><td>25.1%</td><td>-3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A3</td><td>Frank</td><td>Mint</td><td>44</td><td>12.59</td><td>44.2%</td><td>-12</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A21</td><td>Joe</td><td>Thomas</td><td>45</td><td>15.25</td><td>44%</td><td>+12</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A12</td><td>Tess</td><td>Evans</td><td>66</td><td>13.59</td><td>23%</td><td>+4</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A21</td><td>Peter</td><td>Dunn</td><td>12</td><td>2.99</td><td>21.1%</td><td>+2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A33</td><td>Harry</td><td>Jones</td><td>13</td><td>19.49</td><td>22.2%</td><td>-6</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A13</td><td>John</td><td>James</td><td>16</td><td>13.89</td><td>42.1%</td><td>-13</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A71</td><td>Nick</td><td>Parker</td><td>45</td><td>13.89</td><td>44%</td><td>+29</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A21</td><td>Charles</td><td>Dunn</td><td>19</td><td>15.49</td><td>22%</td><td>+3</td></tr><tr><td>A43</td><td>Peter</td><td>Parker</td><td>28</td><td>9.99</td><td>20.3%</td><td>+3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A255</td><td>John</td><td>Hood</td><td>33</td><td>19.99</td><td>25.1%</td><td>-7</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A33</td><td>Clark</td><td>Kent</td><td>18</td><td>15.49</td><td>44.2%</td><td>-13</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A11</td><td>Bruce</td><td>Almighty</td><td>45</td><td>153.19</td><td>44%</td><td>+19</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A102</td><td>Bruce</td><td>Evans</td><td>56</td><td>153.19</td><td>23%</td><td>+9</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A23</td><td>Mike</td><td>Peters</td><td>22</td><td>5.69</td><td>20.3%</td><td>+2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A55</td><td>Leslie</td><td>Kent</td><td>33</td><td>15.99</td><td>25.1%</td><td>-3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A3</td><td>Frank</td><td>Mint</td><td>44</td><td>12.59</td><td>44.2%</td><td>-12</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A21</td><td>Joe</td><td>Thomas</td><td>45</td><td>15.25</td><td>44%</td><td>+12</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A12</td><td>Tess</td><td>Evans</td><td>66</td><td>13.59</td><td>23%</td><td>+4</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A21</td><td>Peter</td><td>Dunn</td><td>12</td><td>2.99</td><td>21.1%</td><td>+2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A33</td><td>Harry</td><td>Jones</td><td>13</td><td>19.49</td><td>22.2%</td><td>-6</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A13</td><td>John</td><td>James</td><td>16</td><td>13.89</td><td>42.1%</td><td>-13</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A71</td><td>Nick</td><td>Parker</td><td>45</td><td>13.89</td><td>44%</td><td>+29</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A21</td><td>Charles</td><td>Dunn</td><td>19</td><td>15.49</td><td>22%</td><td>+3</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `.wrapper` is targeting the div wrapping both tables, but the sticky header is only being added to the first one.

In this case, I would rename the wrapper class & initialize tablesorter pointing to the associated class ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/6cw0qys4/1/))

CSS

```
.wrapper0, .wrapper1 {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 5px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper0">
    <table class="tablesorter">
        ...
    </table>
</div>

<div class="wrapper1">
    <table class="tablesorter">
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(function(){

    $(".tablesorter").each(function(i){
        $(this).tablesorter({
            widthFixed : true,
            headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}', // Add icon for various themes

            widgets: [ 'zebra', 'stickyHeaders', 'filter' ],

            widgetOptions: {
                // jQuery selector or object to attach sticky header to
                stickyHeaders_attachTo : '.wrapper' + i
            }
        });
    });    

});
```